# DatagridView Cell Painting not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, paint

I have a form that loads a `DataGridView`. I created a `CellPainting` event to color the rows based on cell values. I did a `CellPainting` because iterating back over the rows in the `Datagridview` and painting them took WAY too long, so this is more efficient.

**The problem(s)**

- The `CellPainting` event does not for form load. Meaning all the rows are hidden, until I scroll or click on them, then they are painted correctly based on cell values.
- The other thing I noticed is that the Column Headers are missing. Other issue is when I scroll down the `DataGridView` Rows with the scroll bar, the `CellPainting` is called again, and I have to wait several seconds as it repaints the row colors. This is quite annoying especially when I have thousands of rows, and scrolling causes a delay every time I scroll.

All of these issues go away, and the `DatagridView` column headers and rows all appear when I remove the `CellPainting` method, so the problem is obviously there.  Below is my snippet, and help is appreciated.

```
private void timeLineDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
        //only bold and/or color the rows that are false
                if ((Boolean)timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value == false)
                {
                    //get timestamp and go ahead and bold it 
                    DateTime eventTime = DateTime.Parse(timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TIMESTAMP"].Value.ToString());
                    timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = this.boldFont;


                        if (eventTime < this.delay_warn_time3)
                        {
                            timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        else if (eventTime < this.delay_warn_time2)
                        {
                            timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                        }
                        else if (eventTime < this.delay_warn_time1)
                        {
                            timeLineDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I will remember that on future posts, thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [**DataGridView.CellFormatting**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event instead. *Occurs when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display.*

It should be more appropriate in this case.

**EDIT**

It seems that it solved all issues except the *scrolling issue*.

> how do I get the CellFormatting Event to not fire when I scroll

You could add a flag in your class (a boolean variable) that you use in your `DataGridView.CellFormatting` method to test if the grid is scrolling, and then `DataGridView.Scroll` Event to mark this flag.

```
bool _IsScrolling = false;
void DataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll) 
        {
        _IsScrolling = false;
    } else 
        {
        _IsScrolling = true;
    }
}
```

This is a *theorical* answer. If you try and that doesn't work (`e.Type` is never `ScrollEventType.EndScroll`), you will be interested by :

- [DataGridView Scroll event (and ScrollEventType.EndScroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785200/datagridview-scroll-event-and-scrolleventtype-endscroll), that describes the possible bug
- [How can I receive the "scroll box" type scroll events from a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472389/how-can-i-receive-the-scroll-box-type-scroll-events-from-a-datagridview/767603#767603), that is the workaround suggested in the post above.

Comment: Interesting. It solves the headers issue, and it solves the rows hidden issue. The only thing that is left is the repainting / formatting when I scroll. That is still delayed dramatically as I scroll up or down. Is there a way to say "don't do this when scrolling"?

Comment: @scryptKiddy Did you remove `CellPainting` handler? `CellFormatting` event shouldn't cause this behavior if you don't change value during scrolling. What do you mean by Is there a way to say *"don't do this when scrolling"*?

Comment: Yes, CellPainting Event removed. I meant, how do I get the CellFormatting Event to not fire when I scroll, because it is being called (rightfully so) when I scroll. This causes it to have a delay while its 'reformatting'. 
So if there are 1000 rows in the datagridview, and I can see 50, each time I scroll down to see more rows, I have to wait for the CellFormatting Event handler to reformat the cells, causing a delay. Its kind of like a youtube video with a bad buffer is the best way I can describe the behaviour.

Comment: Okay, that fixes the hesitation, 'buffering' effect, but it has another side effect. The above code in your edit works, form loads, and I can immediately scroll the DGV without any pause / hesitation while its reformatting. But what I noticed is only the first set of visible rows are effected with the desired row color. Meaning If I can only see 50 rows, as I scroll to see additional rows, none are painted with the back color that need to be based on the conditional if blocks. Basically, the Scroll Event only paints the first visible set of rows in the DGV, not all of them.

Comment: Also noticed all rows lose their color when sorting, so the two remaining issues with the solution are:
1. Only visible rows are colored as per the CellFormatting method, not all of the rows.
2. After a column sort, all rows go back to default coloring and lose any background color assigned after form loaded. 
Ideas?

Comment: @scryptKiddy I can't say. Disable formatting during scrolling is maybe not a *good solution*. You could try at the `EndScroll` point (before `_IsScrolling = false;`) to call `DataGridView.Invalidate();` to make sure all visibles raws are painted with formatting.

Comment: I believe its not possible. I saw this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651702/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-datagridview-to-fire-its-cellformatting-event-for-all) Which clearly shows there is no way to format rows in a DGV that are not visible to the user. THe question poster did state he got it to work using DataBindingComplete event, but of course posted no code or solution.

Comment: @scryptKiddy I am sure that the `DataBindingComplete` event, which *Occurs after a data-binding operation has finished* would help in this case. Did you try with the other solution (`RowPrePaint` event)?

Comment: Sorry, was not able to get back to this all weekend. Tried RowPrePaint, it has same effect as CellFormatting. Both will only format the visible rows. I agree the definition of DataBindingComplete fits, however, within the DataBindingComplete method (object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) neither of which give me access to the Row. So I would have to create a foreach Row in DGV...etc which of course is really slow and was the cause of this post. The issue now is not what method to use, its why wont the method paint the entire DGV. Still testing things...

Comment: Interesting. I'm able to get the DGV to format all rows on an event through a button. Once the DGV is loaded, I called the click event `this.button1.PerfomClick();`. Unfortunately, although it works, I'm back to square one, its REALLY slow, since the foreach has to reiterate over the rows and repaint rows that have already been initialized. The rate is about 2-3 rows per second...and with thousands of rows, its out of the question. Thanks for the help so far Chris, but not sure what else can be done. Painting rows in a DGV might be too slow to consider. Thoughts?

Comment: @scryptKiddy If you iterate rows once `DGV` is loaded, I think that `DGV` refreshes immediatly the changes, but if you use `CellFormatting` event or `RowPrepaint`, DGV waits to reflect the formating that the row is visible. It's why I really think now that disable the event during scrolling is not a good solution. I agree that 1 will be too slow, but I don't know if very better solution than 2. As you said in a previous comment, it seems there are known performance issues of `DGV` when working with a lot of data. I don't know if I can help you more. If I can I will.

Comment: Agree, I think its down to just performance issues at this point. But thanks for the help, it was worth the effort to see if a solution exists, and I learned alot from the different attempts and our discussions. I'm not sure how to give you points for that, let me know if there is some other credit I can give.